# Is there proof anywhere of the continuity of spherical coordinates and cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: calculus, geometry, functions, continuity

Im thinking they are continuous as a composition of continuous functions, but then again. I don't know exactly which specific(precisely speeking) functions are in question.. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the functions for coordinate conversion as a composite and product of elementary continuous functions, i.e. polynomials and trigonometric functions, meaning the functions are continuous.

For exapmle, the $x$ coordinate for spherical coordinates is $x=r\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta)$

which is the product of three continuous functions:

1. $(r, \phi, \theta)\mapsto r$ is continuous, because it is simply a projection (which is continuous)
2. $(r, \phi, \theta)\mapsto \cos(\phi)$ is a composition of a projection and a trigonometric function:
   $$(r,\phi, \theta)\mapsto \phi\mapsto \cos(\phi)$$
3. $r,\phi, \theta)\mapsto\sin(\theta)$... see point $3$.

Comment: So I have proven that : $(r ,\varphi, \theta)\mapsto r \cos(\varphi)\sin \theta $ is continuous that $(r ,\varphi, \theta)\mapsto ,r \cos \theta$ is continuous, and that $(r ,\varphi, \theta)\mapsto r \sin \varphi \sin \theta$ is continuous, how do I put these three for the final form , formally looking at it?

Comment: @JerryWest what "final form"?

Comment: $(r, \varphi, \theta )\mapsto (r \cos \varphi \sin \theta, r \sin \varphi \sin \theta , r \cos \theta)$

Comment: @JerryWest Well, a mapping from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ is continuous if ant only if all its coordinate functions are continuous...